# How to Resolve MaxListenersExceededWarning in Node.js EventEmitter?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

In my Express server logs, I recently encountered the following warning:

**MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.**

I'm uncertain about the meaning of this warning and how to approach debugging or finding the underlying issue & what can be the possible consequences related to this error.

Could anyone share their insights on issue and how to address it?

I reviewed my code to check that I'm not adding event listeners or exit handlers, there only seems to be only one case where exit handler has been used in the written code, which is mentioned below, though this doesn't seem to be the case causing the issue.

```js
Object.keys(mongo.options).forEach((key) => {
  mongoose.set(key, mongo.options[key])
})

mongoose.Promise = Promise
/* istanbul ignore next */
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.prototype.view = function () {
  return { id: this.toString() }
}

/* istanbul ignore next */
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err)
  process.exit(-1)
})

export default mongoose
```

Any help or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.